# Cache for docker build in gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to build docker images in CI task.

With the same configuration from 
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html.

Launches of CI tasks don't share docker build cache. So each launch of CI is very long.

How should I configure ci workers and volumes for use of docker build cache between CI tasks from different commits?

Comment: Do you want to share cache between jobs in a single run, or over completely different pipeline runs?

Comment: I want to share docker build cache between runs from diffirent commits (different pipeline runs)

Answer (score 0):

GitLab offers a [cache-sharing mechanism](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#sharing-caches-across-different-branches), which you can use to share the docker build cache (usually `/var/lib/docker`) between unrelated pipeline runs.

While this sounds straight forward and easy, you may need to [configure your runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#good-caching-practices) depending on how exactly your runners are set up.